# angular user-idle-service issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using the  user-idle-service (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle) for angular.   I am using it for my angular 6 front end application, but am running into issues where my users are getting kicked out prematurely when they are active.

I fire the library as soon as a user logs in to the application.  It works most of the time, but sometimes users are getting prematurely kicked out when they are active in their browser. I am using this only for browser based usage.

In my service class I fire the below, as well as configuration below that. Is there anything in the library I am using obviously wrong? :

```
constructor(private http: Http,
            private router: Router,
            private cookieService: CookieService,
            private userIdle: UserIdleService) {
    this.userIdle.setCustomActivityEvents(merge(
        fromEvent(window, 'mousemove'),
        fromEvent(window, 'resize'),
        fromEvent(document, 'keydown'),
        fromEvent(document, 'touchstart'),
        fromEvent(document, 'touchend'),
        fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
    ));
}

login(credentials: Credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.loginUrl, JSON.stringify(credentials), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    })
        .pipe(map(userDetails => {
            this.setUserDetailsAndExtendExpirationInLocalStorage(userDetails);
            this.startUserIdle();
            this.goToHome();
        }));
}

startUserIdle() {
    this.userIdle.startWatching();
    this.subscriptions.push((this.userIdle.onTimerStart().subscribe()));
    this.subscriptions.push((this.userIdle.onTimeout().subscribe(() => {
        this.logout();
    })));
    this.subscriptions.push(this.userIdle.ping$.subscribe(() => {
        this.refreshToken();
    }));
}

refreshToken() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.refreshUrl, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    }).subscribe(() => {
        // do stuff
    }, () => {
        this.logout();
    });

}

logout() {
    this.goToLogin();
    this.removeUserDetails();
    this.removeSessionToken();
    this.userIdle.resetTimer();
    this.userIdle.stopTimer();
    this.userIdle.stopWatching();
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
    this.setIsLoggedIn(false);
}
```

Also in my app.module.ts file I configure it like below:

```
UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: 900, timeout: 1, ping: 840})
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use this npm, I created it for the same need. It's working perfectly https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn-ng-idle

Comment: @BearNithi This has only a timeout value, not an idle value, right? So this is not really an alternative I think.

Comment: Can you be sure that the error when you do `this.logout();` is for the right reason? Are you refreshing just in time before the refresh token expires, or is this time slipping beyond the expiry?